How is a wave having travelled a longer path length be more in phase than another wave that travelled a shorter path length?
I was going through wave optics and I saw that the wave having travelled more path length was higher in phase as compared to the one having travelled a shorter path length. But isn't this weird?
Because in the wave equation we have $y=A\sin(\omega t-kx)$ so the phase is essentially inversely related to the distance travelled. I saw there were many explanations that they are observed at different instants but can't understand that, please explain.

What is meant exactly by "higher in phase"? The phase can be seen as the entire argument to the $\sin$ function in this case, but the wave function is periodic in this argument...

Do you mean the amplitude of the wave? It would be great if you could post a picture.

See if this animation helps, it is a good example for the equation you wrote in your post.

@Amit That's a great graphic, and I saved it. I don't think it helps explain the question, though. OP: See if you can find a graphic that relates phase, path length, and your concern about the relation between the two.

I think you are perhaps misunderstanding the wave equation $y=A\sin(\omega t-kx)$.
If we fix $t$ (i.e. take a snapshot of the wave at a fixed time) then when we add $\frac {2 \pi} k$ to $x$ the value of $kx$ changes by an amount $2 \pi$. So $y$ is periodic in space with a period of $\frac {2 \pi} k$ i.e. the wave has a wavelength of $\frac {2 \pi} k$.
And if we fix $x$ (i.e. monitor the wave over time at a fixed position) then when we add $\frac {2 \pi} {\omega}$ to $t$ the value of $\omega t$ changes by an amount $2 \pi$. So $y$ is periodic in time with a period of $\frac {2 \pi} {\omega}$ i.e. the wave has a frequency of $\frac {\omega} {2 \pi}$.
Multiplying the frequency by the wavelength we find that the wave has a velocity of $\frac {\omega} k$.
I don't think any of this leads to the conclusion that "the phase is essentially inversely related to the distance travelled".
The key thing when looking at how a wave might interfere with itself when it takes paths of different lengths is the difference in path length, not which path is longer or shorter. If the difference in path length is a whole number of wavelengths then we see constructive interference; if it is half-way between a whole number of wavelengths then we see destructive interference.

The phase (or phase angle) of the wave represented by $y=A\sin(\omega t-kx)$ is the angle $\omega t-kx$. As time $t$ goes on, the phase at a given point (fixed value of $x$) in the wave's path increases, but, at a given time, the phase decreases for increasing $x$, that is for points further forward in the path of the wave.
We could equally justly, though perhaps with less intuitive appeal, represent the same wave by $y=A\sin(kx-\omega t)$. In that case an increase in $x$ would give an increase in phase ($kx-\omega t$), but an increase in $t$, a decrease in phase.
The key thing, physically, is the minus sign, which is present in both equations. It ensures that the phase at time $(t+\Delta t)$ and distance $(x+\frac{\omega}k \Delta t)$ is the same as at time $t$ and distance $x$, in other words we have a wave progressing in the $x$ direction at speed $\frac{\omega}k$.
